# selenium phantomjs NoSuchElementException c#

Tags: c#, selenium, phantomjs, selenium-firefoxdriver

When i change driver from firefoxdriver to phantomJS i get

> OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException. My code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IWebDriver driver = new PhantomJSDriver(); //FirefoxDriver()
            driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(40);
            driver.Url= "https://ppuslugi.mf.gov.pl/?link=VAT&;";
            IWebElement myDynamicElement = driver.FindElement(By.Id("container_b-7"));
            System.Console.Write("Done");
        }
```

When I use phantomJS driver.PageSource is :

```
<html> <head>  </head> <body>  </body>  </html>
```

When i use firefox as driver  i get full code of web page and all works. 
Can I force phantomjs to work properly?

Comment: It works fine. There is no error on my machine. Can you tell us about version of .NET, PhantomJS, and Selenium?

Comment: phantomjs.exe.1.9.2.1 from nuget package, .NET Framework 4.5.2, visual studio 2015

Comment: It is very similar to my machine except the version of PhantomJS. Can you update it to v.2.1.1?

Comment: This is it :) After update everything started working :))